# Import excel data into a tabel with a record matching the excel field

Tags: mysql, excel, import

To explain it better i'll give you an example:

**Database:**

```
Table1

Col1  Col2
bla    1
yuk    2
bzt    3
```

**Excel:**

```
Col1 Col2
 Me   1
 You  2
They  3
```

When i import the excel file i need to replace only the existed value from db table of the col1 with the excel values from the col1 according to its row value from col2 which is the same in both database and excel.

Comment: import the excel sheet into a staging table, then write some sql compare code to insert or update records accordingly

Comment: @pnuts , as long as the Col1 have the value from the excel's col1 it doesn't matter.But it must be done in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can combine `LOAD DATA LOCAl ...` with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` so i would create an import table with:

`create table imptable like table Table1`

Next step i would do the import:

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:\\myfile.csv' into table imptable`

And last but not least copy the data to Table 1:

`insert into Table1 select col1, col2 from imptable on duplicate key update Table1.col1 = imptable.col1`